# Editing some text in a text file in WPF

Tags: c#

I am new to using forms and C # and trying to do an assignment to create a phone book. I have different options in my phone book

- To Add a contact
- To show all contacts
- and To edit a certain contact.

I am having trouble in how to do editing when text is stored in a text file. I have the following code for my add which adds name, phone number and email. How would i be able to edit one of the names from a list of contacts that is saved in the text file?

Add Code:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\class1.txt", append: true);
    try
    {
            string Name01 = firstName.Text;
            string Name02 = lastName.Text;
            string Phone1 = mobile.Text; 
            string Phone2 = homePhone.Text;
            string emailadd = email.Text;
            string Informtion = Name01 + "\n" + Name02 + "\n" + Phone1 + "\n" + Phone2 + "\n" + emailadd;
            writer.WriteLine("---------------");
            writer.WriteLine(Informtion);
            MessageBox.Show("Success!! Contact information added for: " +Name01 + " " +Name02);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }  
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything WPF specific/related in this question. Please consider removing that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your text file is not structured. Unstructured text is very difficult to search and edit programmatically.

Try using XML or JSON formatted text instead which will allow you to work with entries much easier, especially if you use one of the many open source libraries specifically developed to work with entries in these two formats...

Let's take this XML for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SnomIPPhoneDirectory>
  <Title>PhoneList - Snom</Title>
  <DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Friend, First</Name>
    <Telephone>555-456-7890</Telephone>
  </DirectoryEntry>
  <DirectoryEntry>
    <Name>Person, Second</Name>
    <Telephone>555-654-0987</Telephone>
  </DirectoryEntry>
  <SoftKeyItem>
    <Name>F1</Name>
    <Label>Dial</Label>
    <SoftKey>F_ENTER</SoftKey>
  </SoftKeyItem>
</SnomIPPhoneDirectory>
```

Using a library or even XML functionality built into .NET framework it would be trivial to work with phone book entries in the object oriented way where you would not have to do any string parsing.